# Wowza streaming engine manager did not start in 30 seconds

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

While installing Wowza Media Engine, at last step when I click the finish setup then after sometime it says that "**Wowza streaming engine manager did not start in 30 seconds**" and setup is closed. Any proper solution to start it?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the Wowza Streaming Engine installation process, the user is given an option to start the engine when the system starts.  If this option is selected during installation and the engine doesn't start within 30 seconds, the process times out, and the "Wowza streaming engine manager did not start in 30 seconds" message is displayed.

At this point, the engine must be started manually (or the system must be rebooted).
Wowza Streaming Engine can be run as a service or as in standalone mode, and both the engine and manager started to use the UI.

**Windows - as a service:**

Open services.msc, locate the services for both Windows Streaming Engine and Windows Streaming Engine and Manager, and start both services.

**Windows - standalone:**

Run both the `startup.bat` script in /bin and the `startmgr.bat` script in /manager/bin

**Linux - service:**

Open a terminal, and run the following commands: `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngine start` and `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngineManager start`

**Linux - standalone:**

Open a terminal, `cd` to `/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/bin` and run `./startup.sh`.  Then, `cd` to `/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/manager/bin` and run `./startmgr.sh`

You can also check out the full documentation here: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?631

Comment: I have already tried this and receive the following error while starting the service.
Windows could not resume the Wowza Streaming Engine Manager service on Local Computer.
The service did not return an error. This could be an internal Windows error or an internal service error.
If the problem persists, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Sory for my bad English. Your service did not run as Administrator Account. 
Press **Window + R** => Type **Services.msc**. Find **Wowza Streaming Engine 4.1.0** .Double Click or Righ Click => Chose Properties. 
In Log on Tab Checked on Radio button **This Account** and Input your Administrator UserName and password here. You can find another Account by Click Browse. Then Click Ok. 
Finally Restart service and that work for you.
The same for **Wowza Streaming Engine Manager 4.1.0**

Hope this help. (Only for Window or Window Server)